# Define environment variables for cronjob

Tags: environment-variables, cron

I have a `user` cronjob which loads environment variables from `~/.bashrc` using "source" command.

The variables are defined there like:

```
export FOO="bar"
```

However the variables do no appear in the environment.

Why?

System: Debian 10.

Comment: These variables will only be present in the environment of the process that sources `bashrc` and its children.

Comment: I'd say that's what I do: 1. source bashrc; 2. run print env => no sourced variables in printout available.

Comment: You have to use `export` to create variables that will passed to children process. Do you use `export`?

Comment: yes, I do indeed, as in the post.

Comment: Well it should work. You can reproduce it outside of cron: `echo
export my_var=10 > FILE && . FILE`, you should now see `my_var` in
output of `printenv` or just do `echo $my_var`. Make sure that you
don't have some ifs in your ~/.bashrc that make it return before
reaching export, for example `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` near the top or
something like that.